# Does the zero-or-one operator have a formal name?

Tags: regex

Does the zero-or-one operator `?` have a formal name?  By formal name, I mean like the name "Kleene closure" for the zero-or-more operator `*`.

Comment: I've never seen any other name for ? than just zero or one

Comment: It is usually named "optional quantifier", but I am not sure whether it has a name in formal theory. `A?` is equivalent to `(|A)` in theoretical regular expression, so it is redundant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the formal regular expression theory, `?` does not exist. Formal regular expressions are built from union, concatenation and repetition (Kleene star). What you would write as `A?` in a programming implementation of regular expressions would be mathematically expressed as an union with an empty string: `{ɛ} ∪ A`.